# Visual Studio debug error "Error processing launch: Error: Could not attach to main target

Tags: html, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm working on a simple project on Codecademy and wanted to make sure I was on the right track. When I tried to debug the code, however, a simple Google page popped up and then an error reading

The error:

[image]

I'm very new to coding, so I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Could you please update your question with your launch settings?

Answer (score 10):

First, you could try changing the configuration from legacy to a new one

```
"type": "chrome" -->   "type": "pwa-chrome"
```

Second increase timeout to 20 s or whatever you like

to looks like that

```
"configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Launch Chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "type": "pwa-chrome",
      "timeout": 20000,
      "url": "http://localhost:3000",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
```

Comment: Bumping the timeout worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I am using the Debugger for Chrome extension and the same error occurs in version 4.12.9.
In the description of the extension says:

[Debugger for Chrome](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug)

[Extension note description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgA0c.png)

1. Open the settings of Visual Studio Code (Ctrl + ,) select the Workspace tab
2. In the section Extensions -> JavaScript Debugger set option Debug > JavaScript: Use Preview to false.

[How to change settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfrLv.png)

I was also helped by installing the previous version of the Debugger for Chrome extension version 4.12.8

Comment: Thanks! I reported the issue here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug/issues/1034

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error, after starting VS Code after a two-month absence.  I've reverted to the previous version of "Debugger for Chrome" and it seems okay now.

Answer (score 0):

This can be resolved by VSCode > Setting > Workspace > Extension > Javascript debugger > Debug - Use Preview = Disable.

This will revert to old behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here I am with visual studio code version 1.57.1.

[image: Visual Studio Code Version 1.57.1]

I get the following error.

[image: Error Processing attach error on Visual Studio Code]

Press Ctrl + Shift + P to Open settings

[image: Ctrl + Shift + P to Open settings in Visual Studio Code]

Select Open Settings JSON under Preferences.

Add the following setting

```
"debug.javascript.usePreview": false
```

[image: Settings File in Visual Studio Code]

Save the file, restart vs code and try now.

Answer (score 0):

also had this problem on last versions (VSCode 1.76 with integrated JS debugging, Angular 14).
Unable to make the "Launch Chrome against localhost" work, I received a simple error with no stacktrace "Could not attach to main target".
After days I finally found the reason, the powershell execution policy.
Changing it from AllSigned to RemoteSigned resolved everything.

```
Get-ExecutionPolicy
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

When want to debug the react application in VSCode(v.182.2).Then specify the main html file from where application start.

My launch file look like

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Chrome",
        "url": "http://localhost:3000",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/index.html"
    }
]
```

}

in above code webroot value is important.
Hope this will help you. I struggled on the same 4-5 hours

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that you always run the Visual Studio Code and Browser under the same User, these articles helped me to understand that, had the same issue:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/unable-to-attach-to-the-process?view=vs-2022

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/browser-debugging#_attaching-to-browsers

[image]